# How we get value from its tag

Tags: ios, objective-c

I get the tag value from TapGesture of Textview.Now my question is how we get string value from its text. this is my code

```
-(void)contactselected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UITextView *text = (UITextView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)text.tag);
    NSString *button=(NSString *)[gestureRecognizer.view viewWithTag:text.tag];
    NSLog(@"%@",button);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `UITextView` class reference?

Comment: Do you need to get the text in the textview

Comment: Yes . I want to get value of textview.But my Textview is on another class.

Comment: Yes I m looking get text in the textview

Comment: @user3651677 If you have already accessed the textView then what is the problem in accessing the text from it. I mean simply use  UITextView *text = (UITextView *)gestureRecognizer.view;  then test.text

Comment: @user3651677 are you sure, you are accessing a text view     UITextView *text = (UITextView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
using this code as the error you mentioned below answer says it is THContactBubble?

Comment: can anybody please tell me what is this 'THContactBubble'

Comment: yes i m sure i m acessing textview but my text view is on another class and i m using tap gesture and selector method is on another view controller

Comment: Thcontactbubble is textview

Comment: @interface THContactBubble : UIView <UITextViewDelegate>

Comment: Ok then first use a check before accessing the text view if([text isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) { NSLog(@"%@",text.text);} so if you are right then it will give you the text you needed

Comment: this code not executed

Comment: yes ur right......thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *lTapGestureRecognizer1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(contactselected:)];
lTapGestureRecognizer1.delegate=self;
[self.mDescritionTextview_ addGestureRecognizer:lTapGestureRecognizer1];
```

In the above way add the tap gesture to the textview

```
-(void)contactselected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UITextView *text = (UITextView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)text.tag);
    NSLog(@"%@",text.text);
}
```

If you exaclty need the text from the textview, this code will work and I have tested it now it is working fine